# T-SQL find all records in a group with a max last modified date beyond a specific threshold

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a Database table that has all the information I need arranged like so:

Inventory_ID | Dealer_ID | LastModifiedDate

Each Dealer_ID is attached to multiple Inventory_ID's.  What I need is a query that calculates the Max Value LastModifiedDate for each dealer ID and then gives me a list of all the Dealer_ID's that have a last modified date beyond the last 30 days.

Getting The max last modified date for each Dealer_ID is simple, of course:

```
Select Dealer_ID, Max(LastModifiedDate)as MostRecentUpdate
```

from Inventory group by Dealer_ID order by MAX(LastModifiedDate)

The condition for records older than 30 day is also fairly simple:

```
LastModifiedDate < getdate() - 30
```

Somehow, I just can't figure out a way to combine the two that works properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `HAVING`:

```
Select Dealer_ID, Max(LastModifiedDate)as MostRecentUpdate
from Inventory 
group by Dealer_ID 
having LastModifiedDate < getdate() - 30
order by MAX(LastModifiedDate)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, except for one thing, I needed MAX(LastModifiedDate) in a having clause.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check this query:

```
Select DT.DealerID, DT.MostRecentUpdate
(Select DealerID, Max(LastModifiedDate)as MostRecentUpdate
From YourTable
Group BY DealerID) DT
where DT.MostRecentUpdate < GETDATE() - 30
```